# How to identify and fix cause of 'not set' Event Label in Event report in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics

Custom event tracking is working but includes a lot of 'not set' Event Label entries in the Google Analytics event report.

On our WordPress site we use MonsterInsights Google Analytics plugin (working fine) - we are not using Google Tag Manager. In our theme we leverage this plugin's implementation of the Google Analytics (GA) tracking code to fire a custom event on specific links/buttons. These links either show the contents of the linked page in Colorbox (stays on the calling page) or opens a new window/tab. The code below correctly fires and is tracked in GA - we can navigate to 'Behaviour > Events > colorbox > Play' and see a list of the link/button Titles (Event Label).

However, for some 25% of entries in the GA Events Report there is also a 'not set' listing where only the Event Label hasn't been set.

I have checked our entire website and every occurrence that uses the class 'cbPlayGame' correctly has the 'title' attribute set on the 'a' tag.

Searching the internet keeps coming up with bots and spiders as the cause of 'not set', but quite some time ago in Google Analytics we set up filters to exclude ghost bots etc.

**What might be the cause of these 'not set' entries and could any of them be recorded for genuine users of the website?**

**Is the jQuery code below incorrect or known to not work properly on particular browsers/devices?**

Other questions on here all seem to talk about Google Tag Manager which we don't use or filtering bots which we already do.

Sample link/button:

```
<p class="normalBtn playbtn cbPlayGame"><a href="***URL Removed***" title="3D Violin" class="size720x650">Play <span class="hideele">3D Violin</span></a></p>
```

jQuery GA code:

```
try {
    $j('.cbPlayGame a').click(function(){
        console.log('.cbPlayGame click fired - '+$j(this).attr('title')+'.');
        __gaTracker('send', {
            hitType: 'event',
            eventCategory: 'colorbox',
            eventAction: 'Play',
            eventLabel: $j(this).attr('title')
        });
        console.log('.cbPlayGame ga event sent.');
    });
}
catch(err) {console.log(err);}
```

EDIT - Updated jQuery code:
Now retrieve the link title/href and test if it is populated (not empty, undefined etc) before sending it via __gaTracker.

```
try {
    $j('.cbPlayGame a').click(function(){
        var aTitle = $j(this).attr('title') || this.href;
        console.log('.cbPlayGame click fired aTitle - '+aTitle+'.');
        if(aTitle) {
            __gaTracker('send', {
                hitType: 'event',
                eventCategory: 'colorbox',
                eventAction: 'Play',
                eventLabel: aTitle
            });
            console.log('.cbPlayGame ga event sent.');
        }
        else {
            console.log('.cbPlayGame ga event NOT sent.');
        }
    });
}
catch(err) {console.log(err);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the answer was not isolated to the one bit of jQuery code. It's was a combination of things that by themselves were working fine - but not when used in concert.

1. The jQuery code needed more tests included (see edited code in original question). By including a fallback value of the href for the 'aTitle' showed the source of the 'not set' Google Analytics entries. (Thanks @lcrespilho for leading me to the correct path.)
2. The href from (1.) pointed to a custom WordPress (WP) shortcode code that had been re-used. The 'not set' entry indicated that the shortcode had encountered the one exception it hadn't been designed for.

Adding extra tests to the jQuery and WP shortcode seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know you plugin, but it looks like when you click on the link, the command `$j(this).attr('title')` don't have time to terminate before the page navigates for some 25% of you hits.

Why don't you try to change this code a little bit to evaluate the page title before the __gaTracker call? Something like this:

```js
try {
    var documentTitle = $j(this).attr('title') || document.title;
    $j('.cbPlayGame a').click(function(){
        console.log('.cbPlayGame click fired - '+documentTitle+'.');
        __gaTracker('send', {
            hitType: 'event',
            eventCategory: 'colorbox',
            eventAction: 'Play',
            eventLabel: documentTitle
        });
        console.log('.cbPlayGame ga event sent.');
    });
}
catch(err) {console.log(err);}
```

Make some tests and see if this solves you issue.

Regards.

Comment: You're probably on the right track in that I need to get a value for the title and evaluate if it is populated before executing the __gaTracker code. However, my jQuery code is getting the value of the 'title' attribute on the 'a' link tag, not the document title. The title test would need to be placed inside the click function. I will try it and see how it goes. My only concern is that this would also stop tracking legitimate users who have something 'hinky' stopping the title tracking.

Comment: Hummm... I didn't understand it was the click title. Is there a chance that, maybe, your code is trying to get the attribute "title" of the <span> ? You can try to place a "fake" title attribute on the span just for test purpose also.

Comment: Given the jQuery code is linked to the 'a' tag I'm not sure how the span could have an influence. I have edited my original question to include updated jQuery code where I "prefetch" the title/href value, test if it is empty/undefined etc before sending the __gaTracker event. Now I just need to wait a few days to see how GA responds. If the 'not set' still occurs I suspect that something more sinister is occurring.

Comment: Well thought. Why don't you send a "sinister event" in the else? If (aTitle) { ... } else { __gaTracker('send', { hitType: 'event', eventCategory: 'sinister event', eventAction: 'something', eventLabel: 'something2' }); }

Comment: I'm sure my boss would "appreciate" seeing that in the stats!